# How to mask table fields in Django Rest Serializer

Tags: django, rest

```
class ChatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    creator = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Affairs
        fields = ('creator', 'message', 'date')
```

How can I hide the model fields? I want to get the same result, but have other keys in JSON.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to explain further [by editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53159719/edit) your question on what you want to achieve. At he moment it's still unclear what kind of behaviour you want as your result. For instance, where do you want to hide your model fields? Which fields do you want to hide? Do you still want the data to be passed to the model, but not from the view or form etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the docs say, you can either define fields member var to specify which fields you want included or you can define exclude member var to specify which fields you don't want

```
class ChatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Affairs
        exclude = ('secret', 'hidden', 'waldo')
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include